# How to fix weird behavior for dynamic colors inside XML+Compose app?

Tags: android, xml, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

I wrote single screen in XML and Jetpack Compose. On main screen I have two buttons to different realization of screen. In Jetpack Compose realization dynamic colors works good on different devices and different settings. But for XML realization I have a lot of issues and weird color behavior.

I tested dynamic colors on this devices:

1. Samsung s21 Android 12 One UI 4.0
2. Samsung s21 Android 14 One UI 6.0
3. Pixel 7 Android 14 (ADB device)

I provide some main code aspects of my application below.

colors .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...

    <color name="background_card_color">#FFF2F2F4</color>
    <color name="gray_color">#BFC6CE</color>
    <color name="orange_color">#EF8251</color>
    <color name="background_black_card_color">#181818</color>

    // Light dynamic
    // Primary
    <color name="md_theme_light_primary">@color/orange_color</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_primaryContainer">@color/orange_color</color>
    ...

    // Night dynamic
    // Primary
    <color name="md_theme_dark_primary">@color/orange_color</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_primaryContainer">@color/orange_color</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

In XML files I set dynamic colors like this:

```
android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
```

And in custom views I get dynamic colors like this:

```
val typedValue = TypedValue()
val theme = context.theme
val colorPrimaryResId = com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorOnSecondaryContainer
theme.resolveAttribute(colorPrimaryResId, typedValue, true)
val colorOnSecondaryContainer = ContextCompat.getColor(context, typedValue.resourceId)
```

My theme .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        // Dynamic colors
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now I provide some screenshots of XML screen realizations on different devices with different parameters.

**Dynamic colors off**

Samsung s21 Android 12

[image]

Samsung s21 Android 14

[image]

Pixel 7 Android 14

[image]

**Dynamic colors on**

The same result I get. What am I doing wrong with XML screen realization? If you have some repositories with realization dynamic colors in XML, please give me a link.

Comment: I also found Google codelab with XML dynamic colors. But dynamic colors not work on device. This one — https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-tip-calculator-app-solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. My Theme file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_dark_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_primaryContainer</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/md_theme_dark_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_onSecondaryContainer</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_dark_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_dark_onSurface</item>
</style>
```

And main part is that I downgrade my Material library from 1.11.0 to 1.10.0. And everything works. XML Preview of dynamic colors and also my app is fine now.